# How can we give access to all the files in android 11 in react native using RNFS

Tags: react-native

I have stored file in Download folder but when App running in Android 11 then it's not able to read that stored file and same app is properly able to read file in android 10 , Please help me out what should I change in my code and I am targeting app to SDK 30

Comment: Facing same problem have you got any answer?